# Parsing HTML table with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to get the information like this, especially the text after the strong tag, how can do this by beautifulsoup, thank you.

```
<span class=JamalsinRed>H.S. AHMED ALLY</span>              
<hr align="left" width="400" color="#CCCCCC">
<strong>Address : </strong>217/7,Saleh Market,Adamjee Road,Saddar<br>
<strong>City : </strong>Rawalpindi<br>
<strong>Phone # : </strong>(92 51) 5511748, 5125396<br>
<strong>Fax : </strong>(92 51) 5511749<br>
<strong>E-mail : </strong><a class=b href='mailto:hsaforce@cyber.net.pk'>hsaforce@cyber.net.pk</a><br><strong>Web : </strong>
<a target=_blank href='http://www.hsahmedally.com'>www.hsahmedally.com</a><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to make a nice reusable function that takes a field name as argument and outputs field value. The function would search for the `strong` element with [text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) starting with the field name passed in and [get the next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <span class="JamalsinRed">H.S. AHMED ALLY</span>
    <hr align="left" width="400" color="#CCCCCC">
      <strong>Address : </strong>217/7,Saleh Market,Adamjee Road,Saddar<br>
      <strong>City : </strong>Rawalpindi<br>
      <strong>Phone # : </strong>(92 51) 5511748, 5125396<br>
      <strong>Fax : </strong>(92 51) 5511749<br>
      <strong>E-mail : </strong><a class=b href='mailto:hsaforce@cyber.net.pk'>hsaforce@cyber.net.pk</a><br><strong>Web : </strong>
      <a target=_blank href='http://www.hsahmedally.com'>www.hsahmedally.com</a><br>
    </hr>
</div>
"""

def get_field_value(soup, field):
    return soup.find('strong', text=lambda x: x.startswith(field)).next_sibling

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print get_field_value(soup, 'Address')
print get_field_value(soup, 'City')
```

Prints:

```
217/7,Saleh Market,Adamjee Road,Saddar
Rawalpindi
```